# Trying to use the same app component in 2 different views

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use my root app component in two different views, but it is only rendering the html from app.component.html in one of the views. I'm not sure why and was wondering if this can be done.

For example, I'm I have this in two views:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

Thanks

Comment: There can only be one reference to the root component. You need to create a sub component under your root component to do that.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I'm just learning Angular2 now. Thanks for the information.